# SEH exception with code 0xc00000fd thrown in the test body

Tags: c++, googletest

I am trying to test a class using Google Test. Here is the class definition.

```
class Base
{
    // Some functions

    Signal objSignal[10];
};
```

I am writing tests for the class Base. If I do not create the object objSignal of the class Signal, my tests run fine and no issues. However, when I create the object, I get the following error:

First-chance exception at 0x01274627 in Tests.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
unknown file: error: SEH exception with code 0xc00000fd thrown in the test body.

I am not sure what could be wrong. I tried to delete objSignal in the destructor of Base class. Still same error.

Can you please help me out?

Best Regards

Chintan

Comment: Try seeing what is sizeof(Signal) equal to. If it is big and if (many) objects derived from Base (or of type Base itself) are created on stack you could get SO.

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue. So I was creating an array of 100, which was apparently too big. So I reduced it by half and tests run perfectly fine. Thanks.

Comment: @chintans ran into a simliar error, how can an array of 100 be too big?